# Can you keep a statically assigned NIC alive even when there are no connections in windows?

Tags: windows, nic

I have a NIC that is set to a static IP and has a bunch of optional connections that it is supposed to listen for. I'd like this to be listening whether or not a Ethernet cable is plugged in (in case someone plugs one in after the software has been on without having to check for that). Is this even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the software explicitly binds to a particular address (or set of addresses) it will accept connections on all addresses, including addresses that were not active at the time the listen request was issued.  So you shouldn't have to do anything special, the behaviour you are asking for is the default.

Comment: Yeah, but I have multiple NICs so I need to specify the address :-P

Comment: You mean, you want to only listen on that particular NIC?  Could you instead listen on all NICs and explicitly reject connections that aren't coming from the right one?